# Use ActiveRecord::SessionStore for sessions in Sinatra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, activerecord, sinatra

I want to store the session data in database using the ActiveRecord::SessionStore module. I have been searching for quite sometime for this without success. Either i am not using the proper search terms or i am being blind to something very obvious.

I have used this statement `require ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session` in my code to enable session handling with active record. It conks out with the error **uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ActionDispatch** . I assume that i have install the actiondispatch module. Am I correct?

Please bear in mind that this is my first shot with Ruby-Sinatra. I am coming from PHP.

So, what should i use to make Sinatra use database-based sessions using ActiveRecord?

Comment: did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: @andicrook Nope, moved onto Rails.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up solving the `uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ActionDispatch` error by adding the `actionpack` gem to my application's Gemfile and requiring `action_dispatch`. You might also have to `require 'logger'`

Answer (score 1):

Sinatra is a [Rack](http://rack.rubyforge.org/) based application and allows addition of middleware. Middlewares can be plugged into any Rack based framework. 
Search on references of config.ru in the [Sinatra Book](http://sinatra-book.gittr.com/)

so you would create a config.ru file in the root of your app.
and put something like this

```
require 'my_app'
use ActiveRecord::SessionStore
run MyApp
```